# Debugging a jQuery plugin to display a dynamic list in two equal columns

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, typeerror, joomla3.0

I am trying to implement a jQuery plugin. The code is available on jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/MKL4g/1/ but I have also copied my modifications below.

```
var postsArr = new Array(),
    $postsList = $('div.cat-children ul');

//Create array of all posts in lists
$postsList.find('li').each(function(){
    postsArr.push($(this).html());
})

//Split the array at this point. The original array is altered.
var firstList = postsArr.splice(0, Math.round(postsArr.length / 2)),
    secondList = postsArr,
    ListHTML = '';

function createHTML(list){
    ListHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        ListHTML += '<li>' + list[i] + '</li>'
    };
}

//Generate HTML for first list
createHTML(firstList);
$postsList.html(ListHTML);

//Generate HTML for second list
createHTML(secondList);
//Create new list after original one
$postsList.after('<ul class="cat-list"></ul>').next().html(ListHTML);
```

I am implementing this on a Joomla 3.0.2 site using the Gantry 4.1.5 Framework.

The CSS to style the resulting UL LI array is as follows (LESS Format):

```
body {
  &.menu-face-à-la-crise,
  &.menu-divorce-séparation,
  &.menu-études-de-cas,
  &.menu-effets-de-la-vie-séparée,
  &.menu-effets-du-divorce,
  &.menu-effets-communs,
  &.menu-situations-particulières,
  &.menu-formulaires-modèles,
  &.menu-suppléments-addendas,
  &.menu-à-propos-de-nous {
    div#rt-mainbody-surround {
      margin-top: -1px;
      background: @whitebrown;
    }
    div.component-content {
      .blog {
        li {
          text-align: center;
          font-family: @headingFontFamily;
          font-weight: 700;
          font-size: 2.0em;
          line-height: 1.5em;
          text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
        }
        div.cat-children {
            ul {
              float: left;
              padding: 10px;
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error in the console:

**TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating '$postsList.find')**

You can see the implementation here:

http://gobet.ergonomiq.net/études-de-cas/effets-du-divorce

As you can see, it doesn't seem to take the list items and split them into two columns.

The resulting display should split the list into two columns, and have the list items be visually centred to the columns.

Can someone advise how to debug and resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have MooTools enabled and at the beginning of your script. Flip it so that you're using the jQuery selectors.

```
var postsArr = [],
    $postsList = jQuery('.cat-children ul');

//Create array of all posts in lists
$postsList.find('li').each(function(){
    postsArr.push(jQuery(this).html());
})

//Split the array at this point. The original array is altered.
var firstList = postsArr.splice(0, Math.round(postsArr.length / 2)),
    secondList = postsArr,
    ListHTML = '';

function createHTML(list){
    ListHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        ListHTML += '<li>' + list[i] + '</li>'
    };
}

//Generate HTML for first list
createHTML(firstList);
$postsList.html(ListHTML);

//Generate HTML for second list
createHTML(secondList);
//Create new list after original one
$postsList.after('<ul class="cat-list"></ul>').next().html(ListHTML);
```

---

edit for the new request

```
(function updateColumns($){
    var postsArr = [],
        $postsList = $('.cat-children ul'),
        $parent = $postsList.parent();

    //Create array of all posts in lists
    $postsList.find('li').each(function(){
        postsArr.push(jQuery(this).html());
    })

    //Split the array at this point. The original array is altered.
    var firstList = postsArr.splice(0, Math.round(postsArr.length / 2)),
        secondList = postsArr,
        // ListHTML = '', <-- not needed
        $insertWrapper = $('<div>').addClass('cat-children');

    function createHTML(list){
        var $ul = $('<ul>').addClass('cat-list');
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            $ul.append( $('<li>').html( $(list[i]).html() ) );
        };
        var $wrappedDiv = $('<div>').addClass('gantry-width-50 cat-columns').append( $ul )
        return $wrappedDiv;
    }

    //Generate HTML for first list
    $insertWrapper.append( createHTML(firstList) );
    $insertWrapper.append( createHTML(secondList) );

    $postsList.replaceWith( $insertWrapper );
})(window.jQuery);
```

Comment: is there an easy way to wrap the two generated columns in divs? I'd like each column wrapped in `<div class="gantry-width-50 gantry-width-spacer cat-columns"></div>` and then at the end have a `<div class="clear"></div>`. Someone on chat suggested wrapInner, but I'm not sure how to use that, and it may just be easier to modify the output (starting at `createHTML`?

Comment: it _seems_ like 'gantry-width-50' is a class from the framework you're using, is that accurate? If so, it probably means "a 50% wide column" but I would have to see the CSS declaration on that.

Comment: I'll make a slight addition to the post above

Comment: yes, it is. `.gantry-width-spacer {margin: 15px;}` and `.gantry-width-50 {width: 50%;}`. Pretty simple really. and cat-columns is just a class I'd like to add in case I need to make further adjustments to those divs.

Comment: I didn't yet add `.gantry-width-*` because I want you to take this in gradual stages. Use the above code and ensure it gives the output you want and that you understand how it works. I may have goofed and forgotten an element. I made it what's called "fluent" where each action is definitively self-controlled, easily legible, and intentful.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23156/discussion-between-alisamii-and-jcolebrand)